# Posting JSON to RestApi returns ErrorCode 500 bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to post a simple Object to an Web API.

The object is like below

```
public class Subscription
{
    [JsonProperty("subscriber")]
    public Subscribe subscribe { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Subscribe
{
    [JsonProperty("mailinglist_ids")]
    public string[] mailinglist_ids { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subscriber")]
    public Subscriber subscriber { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Subscriber
{
    [JsonProperty("foreign_id")]
    public string foreign_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}
```

The code for posting using RestSharp is

```
var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.Resource = ressource;
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic APITOKEN");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddBody(subscription);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I can see the subscription object is passed as a paramter correctly but the value is escaped, which causes the Web Api to return an 500 error.

Can i prevent escaping strings i C# or is there any other way to post data

Comment: 500 is an Internal Server Error.  400 is a Bad Request.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid constructing the JSON manually, which can lead to errors, use the `AddJsonBody()` with an object representing the data to serialize

Adding the `subscription` to the body as json.

```
Subscription subscription = new Subscription() {
    //..assuming it is populated
};

//...

//Serializes obj to JSON format and adds it to the request body.
request.AddJsonBody(subscription);
```

Comment: I'm not constructting the JSON manually. The subscription object is  the native object. Setting request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json and request.AddBody(subscription) should be the same as request.AddJsonBody. Which i also tried with the same result.

Comment: Inspect the raw request and show what is being sent. you say it is being escaped. Show that

Comment: The request body contains the escaped string on which the webapi returns an 500 error. I've tried different enviroments Web/Winforms but maybe its in the nature of C#